# Script doesn't run when requests module is imported

Tags: python

I am creating .bat to run code which includes importing requests module. It works perfectly in PyCharm but when I ran .bat it does not work. Other modules i.e. webbrowser works fine in PyCharm and in .bat script. Why it is not working with the requests module?

Comment: depends on the environment and python version.  are they the same for pycharm and the system ?

Comment: Python 3.10 and Virtualenv

Comment: that is probably why then.  Expect that you installed modules in the virtual environment that you do not have in the standard environment...   so works in venv but not standard.

Comment: Thanks! Which env I shall use then?

Comment: i generally do not build code in a venv because i run it straight from my PC or laptop. the purpose of the venv is to keep modules contained inside.  So, get the same working without a venv in pycharm and it will be consistent with the pc.

Comment: there are two possibilities: (1) install `requests` without `venv` and `.bat` should work (and this is method which I use). (2) find folder with virtual environment for your project and there should be script to `activate` this venv - and run this script inside `.bat` before you run python in `.bat` (2 - little different) when you run `activate` then it sets different path to `python` - if you will have this path then you can run `/full/path/to/this/python script.py` without running `activate`. You can get this path if you use `print( sys.executable )` when you run in PyCharm

Comment: `webbrowser` works because it is standard module installed with Python

Comment: @furas how I can install requests without venv and .bat. Tried to google it and all I can find is to use 'python -m pip install requests' in cmd, but even it is installed .bat still does not work me.

Comment: you may have many pythons installed and `python -m pip ...` may install module in one Python but you still can run code with different Python. In python code (which you run with .bat) use `import sys` and `print( sys.executable )` to see `/full/path/to/python` and later in console/terminal use this path to install module `/full/path/to/python -m pip install ...`